# Поиск в wordpress не работает

Tags: php, wordpress, search

Помогите пожалуйста, пытаюсь натянуть на стандартную тему  Поиск, но он не работает, проблема в названии стандартной темы, пытаюсь её переделать, но тщетно. Также ищу человека(ментора) по Wordpress, кто сможет уделять максимум 10 минут в день для помощи, в любое удобное для него время

```
<header class="page-header">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'detua-theme' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'detua-theme' ); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
</header><!-- .page-header -->

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /**
             * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'excerpt' );

        endwhile; // End of the loop.

        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text' => detuatheme_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'detua-theme' ) . '</span>',
            'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'detua-theme' ) . '</span>' . detuatheme_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'detua-theme' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );

    else : ?>

        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'detua-theme' ); ?></p>
        <?php
            get_search_form();

    endif;
    ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: Что именно с поиска не работает? Не идет запрос с формы? Или не выводятся посты - результат поиска?

Comment: Выдает ошибку:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function detuatheme_get_svg() in C:\OSPanel\domains\detwordpress\wp-content\themes\detua-theme\search.php on line 43

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function detuatheme_get_svg() in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\detwordpress\wp-content\themes\detua-theme\search.php
>   on line 43

Ошибка указывает, что функция `detuatheme_get_svg()` не найдена. Посмотрите файл **functions.php** темы которую Вы переделываете, там эта функция должна быть. Так как она используется в стандартной функции **wordpress** `the_posts_pagination()`, скорее всего, она нужна что бы вывести стрелки в пагинации постов. Можно обойтись и без этой функции.

Документация по выводу пагинации в wordpress есть в [кодексе](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination)(англ.) или на [wp-kama](https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_posts_pagination)(рус.)